# How to interface SIM800L to UART on STM32F103

Tags: microcontroller, c, stm32, serial, uart

I have problem to interface SIM800L with STM32F103. I just read SIM800L datasheet that UART logic level is on 2.8 V. But the STM32F103,can be operated in 3.3 V. I connected my TX RX pin directly to my MCU. I send AT command but nothing happen. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You have to use RS232 interface IC like MAX232 for level shifting.

Comment: I use it too and the result is same. But in this case, i want to interfacing sim800l and stm32f103. I think MAX232 is converting ttl serial to cpu serial and vice versa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to check the I/O and serial port characteristics in the datasheet of the devices to be sure that logic levels are matched. You need the **V<sub>IL</sub>, V<sub>IH</sub>, V<sub>OL</sub>, V<sub>OH</sub>** respectively for the [SIM800L](http://wiki.seeedstudio.com/images/4/46/SIM800L_Hardware_Design_V1.00.pdf) and the [STM32F103](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/33/d4/6f/1d/df/0b/4c/6d/CD00161566.pdf/files/CD00161566.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00161566.pdf). For the SIM800:

[image]

For the STM32F103 the input values that are tested in production:

- **V<sub>IL</sub>max** = 0.35 * VDD = 0.35 * 3.3 V = **1.155 V**
- **V<sub>IH</sub>min** = 0.65 * VDD = 0.65 * 3.3 V = **2.145 V**

Theoretically **V<sub>IL</sub>** a bit higher and **V<sub>IH</sub>** a bit lower.

[image]

As you can see there is no problem here as the SIM800's **V<sub>OL</sub>max** (0.1 V) is below the STM32's **V<sub>IL</sub>max** (1.155 V). And the SIM800's **V<sub>OH</sub>min** (2.7 V) is above the STM32's **V<sub>IH</sub>min** (2.145 V).

The other direction, STM32F103 output values:

[image]

There are several cases, you should calculate with the worst case values, so when the IO current is +20 mA. **V<sub>OL</sub>max** = 1.3 V and  **V<sub>OH</sub>min** = 3.3 V - 1.3 V = 2 V.

Now, here come the problems as the SIM800's **V<sub>IL</sub>max** is 0.3 V but the STM32's **V<sub>OL</sub>max** is at least 0.4 V. There is a 0.1 V gap in which the input to the SIM800 is undefined.

Also the STM32's **V<sub>OH</sub>min** can be 2 V, 2.4 V or 2.9 V. The 2 V is far below the SIM800's **V<sub>IH</sub>min** 2.5 V. The 2.9 V would probably be fine.

---

All in all logic level conversion is suggested, it is mentioned in the SIM800's datasheet as well along with a reference circuit.

[image]

---

If your problem persist after doing the level shifting, here are a couple of items that you should check:

- You should check that you connected the SIM800's TX pin to the STM32's RX pin and the SIM800's RX pin to the STM32's TX pin.
- SIM800 has autobauding enabled by default, and autobauding supports only the following baudrates: 1200, 2400, 4800, 9600, 19200, 38400 and 57600. So if your baudrate is 115200 then that should be changed.
- Make sure that every AT command you send ends with `\r\n` sequence.